# Using Sails.js build, where are my client side files?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

From website:

"sails build spits out a ready-to-deploy `www` directory for use in all of the sorts of places where you need indepenedent, API-driven front-end code"

When I look at `www` folder I dont see the HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the grunt task **builProd** located under *"tasks/register/buildProd.js"*, you can realize that the task is actually creating the "**www**" folder is "copy:build", which only copy everything inside the *".tmp/public"* folder.

I assume sails uses the .ejs files located under ./views

Answer (score -1):

The served "website" is deployed to .tmp/public folder in sailsjs 0.10. The folder is automatically created out of the /assets "source" folder. That is, you put your js/CSS/imgs/HTML template files in the /assets folder and it will be copied to /.tmp/public and served from there. Additionally, it will compile less files, inject js and CSS files in the view layout.

Comment: I know this, I took a basic sails .10 project. Ran sails build. I didnt see HTML or ejs files in www folder. So, www cant be copied and moved to a webserver which requires assets to be in www folder

Comment: When you say "www folder" you mean ".tmp/public" folder? Because in sails, the "www folder" is actually .tmp/public.

BTW: the html file should be placed in the assets/templates folder and it will be copied to the .tmp/public/templates folder.

Comment: No. I mean "www" folder in .10 "sails www" creates a production version of code. In that folder I dont see any ejs or html files.